# VBA Excel Get Cell Address or Value by Row containing "X" and Column containg "Y"

Tags: excel, vba

The main goal is to get the value of the Cell where Row that contains "NQQ" intersect with Column that contains "Revenue", i highlighted the Cell with yellow color.

Till now i just succed to get the row nr which contains "NQQ" and i get stucked.

```
'Find row of NQQ
    Columns("A:A").Select 
    Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:="NQQ", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    CellNr = Cell.Row
```

[image]

Comment: If your maingoal is to get the value, as per your current sample data, you could get it with `SUMIF`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the same logic to Revenue, and use the `Row` and `Column` properties of the found ranges. Always incorporate a check when using `Find` that the search has found the item to avoid errors.

You can do this with formulae, btw.

```
Sub x()

Dim Cell As Range, Cell1 As Range

Set Cell = Columns("A:A").Find(What:="NQQ", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
Set Cell1 = Rows(1).Find(What:="Revenue") 'assume revenue is in row 1

If Not Cell Is Nothing And Not Cell1 Is Nothing Then 'avoid error if one or both not found
    MsgBox Cells(Cell.Row, Cell1.Column).Address
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Add As String
Add = Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match("NQQ", Range("A:A"), 0), "C").Address
Debug.Print Add
```

If "Revenue" column is not always in the same position, use this code:

```
Add = Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match("NQQ", Range("A:A"), 0), _
            WorksheetFunction.Match("Revenue", Range("1:1"), 0)).Address
Debug.Print Add
```